# distr package-how to draw two plots in one window?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using `distr` to form the following distributions:

```
library(distr)

G1 <- Gammad(shape=1.64, scale=0.766)
G2<- Gammad(shape=0.243, scale=4.414)
```

now in order to compare these two distributions I need to plot them in one window, but I don't know how. I tried `ggplot` but apparently it does not work with gamma function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using ggplot

you can use `stat_function`

eg

```
# data that defines the range of x values you are interested in
DF <-data.frame(x = c(1,8))
ggplot(DF, aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = d(G1), aes(colour = 'G1')) + 
  stat_function(fun = d(G2), aes(colour = 'G2')) + 
  scale_colour_manual('Distribution', 
           values = setNames(c('red', 'blue'), c('G1', 'G2')))
```

[image]

## Using base

The help file for `distr::plot` shows how to combine plots.

You need to set `mfrow` (or `mfcol`) yourself, then set `mfColRow =FALSE` within the plot call.

eg:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(G1, mfColRow=F)
plot(G2, mfColRow=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I am trying to execute your code but apparently DF has not been defined and also sth is missing.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to copy those lines.